# How to get the Instagram API for downloading the stories

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

Is there any way to get the Instagram API from the copy link of the Instagram Story?
For example here is an Instagram Story link that I want to get its API for downloading the contents of the Story

https://instagram.com/stories/videofunclip/2843622667107104235?utm_source=ig_story_item_share&igshid=MDJmNzVkMjY=

Comment: All info can be found here https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?